# Liftweb - WiringUI and attributes bug using AutoComplete

Tags: scala, attr, lift

My problem is happening when I use some attributes in

I have the following error displayed on my webpage:

```
error on line 146 at column 80: AttValue: " or ' expected
```

Here is the corresponding line:

```
try{jQuery("#F114215951950RGX25X").each(function(i) {this.innerHTML = "<span id=\"F114215951957PA3NZS\"></span>";});} catch (e) {}
```

Here is the code in my snippet:

```
import net.liftweb.util.ValueCell
import http.SHtml
import net.liftweb.widgets.autocomplete.AutoComplete

object SearchMenu {

  /* A valueCell on which WiringUI is used */
  val wiringCell= ValueCell(true)

  /* The function called in html template */
  def display = WiringUI.apply(wiringCell)(displayAjax)

  /* The cell to be updated using autocomplete */
  val cell = ValueCell("")

  /* The function to create and display the autocomplete box */
  def displayAjax(value: Boolean)(ns:NodeSeq):NodeSeq = {
    def buildQueryName(current: String, limit: Int): Seq[String] = {
      if (current.length == 0) Nil
      else (1 to limit).map(n => current+""+n).take(limit)
    }
    AutoComplete("", buildQueryName _, cell.set _)
  }
}
```

Here is the code in my HTML page:

```
<form class="lift:form.ajax">
    <div class="lift:display"> </div>
</form>
```

**Note:** the code works if I call `displayAjax(true)` instead of `display`, that is to say, if I don't use Wiring.

**Note:** I think the problem might come from the fact that autocomplete uses a script that is not loaded when using Wiring UI.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `nameAjax`? Have you tried instead `AutoComplete(cell.get, buildQueryName _, cell.set _)`?

Comment: @dave you are right, however when I correct my code, I still have the same problem (I will edit my post accordingly to your remark in order to make my problem simpler to understand)

Comment: However I chose the other formulation to be able to post either from autocomplete or when the user types anything in the text block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like I found 2 bugs in lift for the autocomplete widget. Here is the thread in the official lift mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/liftweb/Zu5DBqSSW4U